# Selenium select checkbox in shadow root

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, shadow-dom

I am using Java Selenium for UI automation.  Try to select checkbox in the shadow root but can not find the element.

```
<prod-checkbox class="class1" >
  #shadow-root(open)
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="" value="false">
     <span class="checkmark"></span>
     <span class="label">production_A</span>
    </label>
</prod-checkbox>

<prod-checkbox class="class1" >
  #shadow-root(open)
   <label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="" value="false">
     <span class="checkmark"></span>
     <span class="label">production_B</span>
    </label>
</prod-checkbox>
```

These two checkboxes have the same className, the only difference is the label text. How can I access to specific one? Tried to do something like `shadow.findElement(parent, cssSelector)` but not sure how to differentiate two checkboxes

Comment: add another class in second checkbox like class="class1 class2" and then select the second class on the base of class2

Comment: @HenlenLee Still not convinced that both the `shadow-root(open)` is `<prod-checkbox class="class1" >` Can you crosscheck once?

Comment: @DebanjanB  It's a dynamic checkbox